# How to make technical training session useful and successful for trainee?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

Are these suggestions good to give for a successful training session?

- Practice time should be always given immediate after technical training?
- usually after receiving any technical session about any new thing we do routine work.
- If we don't do practice just after training, later when we do any work related to that training then we feel we need training again. So if we are getting training today and will not use it for some period of time (15 -30 -60 days) then the training is of no use, as it is at the wrong time. I.e. We will forget many things

Any other suggestions which i should give? I'm trainee not trainer. What suggestion should i give to trainer/organizer?

Comment: What is the syllabus? Programming, or routine IT?

Comment: @Extrakun, according to his tags I'd say HTML, CSS, javascript(framework). But you're right it would be better if he wrote syllabus

Comment: @Extrakun - Training to operate any web based application or CMS or any new things in xhtml css javascript, php etc. any technical training.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, technical training will only be useful if your atendees can go back and start using it. If its new, it may take less than a week for them to forget it.

As for the training. A few things I have learned:

- Plan for about 1 minute per slide
- Don't talk for more than 40 minutes in one session.
- Follow each session with a practical exercise. People like to play - let them.
- Insist that exercises are done in pairs
- Allow 30 minutes for each practical session and include break time within that.
- Start as early as possiblem - you will have the best time between morning and lunch time
- Immediately after lunch is the worst time for learning - schedule a practical for then.
- Schedule courses for early in the week  - Monday is best.
- Be flexible in giving the course - different groups will have different abilities.
- Don't be afraid if you don't have all the answers - I just say "I don't know" and then make sure I look the answer up later.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A better way is first practice then a little technical training then again practice.
The first practice is useful because creates some question about the subject and get the student hungry for the training .

Answer (score 1):

From my own experiences, make sure you have at least 1 hour after training for Q & A. Ask everything you can, write notes and try it straight after. Preferably do it in a comfortable way, don't rush yourself, enjoy the coffee and collaborate with colleagues. You'll see the results.

Also, try to use the learned stuff often, else was your training just a waste of time. You probably won't forget it, but getting back to it 1-2 months after training will be very painful.